# DAX function LOOKUPVALUE returns value from date column as #,0.00

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a measure to lookup value either from Date column or Status column based on the status.

For Eg. If the status is `"In Progress"` then the value in the Date column should be displayed but when the Status is `"Completed"`, output should be just the text `"Completed"`.

| Date | Status | Area | Completion % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30-Jul-2021 | In Progress | Main Office | 75 |
|  | Completed | Garden | 75 |
|  | Completed | Kitchen | 100 |
| 30-Aug-2021 | In Progress | Bed Room | 75 |

```
75CompletionStatus = 
VAR LookedUpVal = LOOKUPVALUE(ComplDates[Status],ComplDates[Completion %],75,ComplDates[Area],"Main Office")
Return
if(LookedUpVal="In Progress", LOOKUPVALUE(ComplDates[Date],ComplDates[Completion %],75,ComplDates[Area],"Main Office"),"Completed")
```

I need this to work retaining the Date column having DataType as `Date`

Currently the output of below measure is displayed as `#,0.00` when I take the output to a card.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out !

```
75CompletionStatus = 
VAR LookedUpVal = LOOKUPVALUE(ComplDates[Status],ComplDates[Completion %],75,ComplDates[Area],"Main Office")
Return
if(LookedUpVal="In Progress", FORMAT(LOOKUPVALUE(ComplDates[Date],ComplDates[Completion %],75,ComplDates[Area],"Main Office"),"dd-mmm-yy"),"Completed")
```

I missed to use FORMAT function.

Suggestion to improve approach are most welcome.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I think I've not elaborated enough about the table. The table consists of work progress for different area of our project. each of the area has a progress indicator in one column named as "Completion %", which has values from 10, 20, 30... 75, ... 100 in each rows with Date or text as "Completed" in adjacent column